# PR trigger for Azure Pipeline building the base PR branch

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a github repository called **apprepo** . In that there is a branch dev2 which i use it as the base branch.

I created another branch out of that **dev3** made some changes to it. In the azure-pr-pipeline.yml the contents are as follows:

```
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - dev2 // include when PR is raised for merging to dev2 branch

stages:
- stage: PR
  displayName: prBuild
  jobs:
   - job: DowndSecureFile
     displayName: Build
     steps:
       - task: NodeTool@0
   inputs:
     versionSpec: '16.x'
   displayName: 'Install Node.js'
 - script: |
    echo "workingdirectory " $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
    npm install
    npm ci
    npm audit fix
    npm run build
```

Now when i make changes in dev3 and raise PR for merging to dev2,build gets triggered but the **dev2** branch (base) is getting built instead of the **dev3** branch where the changes are committed.

Can anyone please tell me, how to checkout the dev3 branch of the **apprepo** and only build that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PR build should run for the PR merge branch (**refs/pull/{PR Number}/merge**), neither the target branch (**dev2**) nor the source branch (**dev3**).

If there is build triggered for the branch which is not the PR merge branch, ensure you have disabled the CI trigger on this YAML pipeline.

For example:

```yaml
trigger: none  // Disable the CI trigger.
pr:
  branches:
    include:
    - dev2
```

By this way, the pipeline will be only triggered by PR, not by the CI trigger from the target branch and the source branch.

Comment: If you do not specify trigger:none in yaml. Pipeline will consider the PR is true. This can be verified in devops portal by Clicking on 'Edit' in pipeline -> Click on 3 dots -> Trigger -> Pull Request validation. You can enable/disable the PR there.

Comment: @Dilly B Hi can you please tell me what do you mean by - Pipeline will consider the PR is true . do you mean if i dont put trigger: none then CI will be triggerred ? I am quite new so only this clarification required. Thanks